# Error Create ASP.net MVC Razor Project

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I am trying to create a razor MVC project

[image]

When creating an error occurs, already I searched but found nothing

[image]

This is the error
An error occurred while applying transformation to 'Web.config' in project 'teste2': Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: key

The log:

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException: An error occurred while applying transformation to 'Web.config' in project 'teste2': Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: key ---> Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlNodeException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: key ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
  at System.Xml.NameTable.Add (System.String key) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlAttribute.set_Prefix (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlElementContext.ScrubTransformAttributesAndNamespaces (System.Xml.XmlNode node) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlElementContext.ScrubTransformAttributesAndNamespaces (System.Xml.XmlNode node) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlElementContext.CreateCloneInTargetDocument (System.Xml.XmlNode sourceNode) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlElementContext.get_TransformNode () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.Transform.get_TransformNode () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.Insert.Apply () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.Transform.ApplyOnce () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.Transform.Execute (Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.XmlElementContext context, System.String argumentString) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on?
I am using Ubuntu 15.10

Thank you

[EDIT]

I could solve the problem by installing the package *mono-devel* according to [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by installing the package *mono-devel* according to [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#usage)